# Using Laravel blade syntax for Bootstrap tabs and routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, bootstrap-tabs

I have already read some links regarding Bootstrap tab in Laravel but none of them is working for me.

I have 3 views (movies, scheduled_movies, group_movies) each view has its respective controller. Now I want to show all these views using bootstrap tab component. I tried a lot, but tabs don't work properly or sometimes all the data of three view shown in the first tab and sometimes only tabs are shown but not the data.

Here is my code-

app.blade.php

```
@include('components.navbar')
@yield('base')
```

base.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('base')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar" >
            @include('components.sidebar')
        </div>
        <main id="main" class="col-10 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-3">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I have separate `tab.blade.php` where all my bootstrap tab code is written. and I have included all 3 views using `@include`

tab.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.base')

@section('content')
<div class="p-3">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="movies-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#movies" role="tab" aria-controls="movies"
                aria-selected="true">All movies</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="scheduled-movies-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#scheduled-movies" role="tab"
                aria-controls="scheduled-movies" aria-selected="false">Scheduled Movies</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="group-movies-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#group-movies" role="tab" aria-controls="group-movies"
                aria-selected="false">Group Movies</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="movies" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="movies-tab">
            @include('movies.all_movies.index')

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="scheduled-movies" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="scheduled-movies-tab">
            @include('movies.scheduled-movies.index')
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="group-movies" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="group-movies-tab">
            @include('movies.group-movies.index')
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

MoviesController

```
class MoviesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $movies = Movie::all();
        return view('movies.all_movies.index')->with('movies', $movies);    
    }
}
```

The same code is written in `ScheduledMoviesController`.

This is my `web.php` file

```
Route::get('movies', 'MoviesController@index');
Route::get('scheduled-movies', 'ScheduledMoviesController@index');
Route::get('group-videos', 'GroupMoviesController@index')->middleware('verified');
```

Till now I have figured out some cases

1. Maybe my blade syntax @yield or @include is wrong.
2. Maybe routing is wrong (because of the first page of the tab showing data from all three).

Comment: Hello, you can  try to check dev-tools from your browser. and check how it is rendering as html. I guess you can find problem.

Comment: @HayreddinTüzel Yes, I have already done that. It shows Bootstrap `active` class for the two tab pane i.e 1st tab and 2nd tab or 1st tab and 3rd. Can you please tell me how should I design my routes.

Comment: Younshould gather all routes as one. There should be only one route for bootstrap tabs

Comment: Okay, @HayreddinTüzel. I will read some more and will try to solve this. Thanks for the suggestion.